# Get array of particular property of model obj based on condition Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, model, ios10

I have a model as follows:

```
class Expertise:NSObject{
var expertise:String = ""
var isSelevted:Bool = false
}
```

I want the array of the selected expertise.

I tried:

```
Obj.filter{$0.isSelected == true}.first.expertise
```

but the above line didn't worked.

Comment: Have you get any error or warning?

Comment: No errors and no warnings

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: I am not getting the array of just expertise using the filter, it just gives the last element not the array

Comment: To get the array just use this Obj.filter{$0.isSelected == true}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the expertise value of each selected object in the array use filter and map:

```
objects.filter { $0.isSelected } .map { $0.expertise }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the first selected expertise.
To get the array of the selected expertise just use this

```
let selectedExpertises = Obj.filter{$0.isSelected == true}
```

Then you can get the expertises names like this

```
for expertise in selectedExpertises {
    print(expertise.expertise)
}
```

Update: to get the array of expertises names :

```
var expertises: [String] = []

let selectedExpertises = Obj.filter{$0.isSelected == true}

 for expertise in selectedExpertises {
    expertises.append(expertise.expertise)
}
```

Another way:

```
var expertises: [String] = []

for expertise in Obj {
    if expertise.isSelected {
        expertises.append(expertise.expertise)
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the array of var expertise which is inside the Model